# Excel: A macro to minus a certain number from a column of cells every 24 hours?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns. The first has 'Usage per day' and the other has 'Amount in stock'. I need a macro that would take the usage per day from the amount in stock every 24 hours so that I will know when I need to re-stock. I think it would need have a separate 'run' button for each cell because I would not be restocking each shelf at the same time so resetting each cell simultaneously may not work. Where would I find out how to make something like this (for a beginner excel user)? Thanks

Comment: You would need a starting date, wouldn't you?

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about it. Are you saying to set a start date as today 12/07/16 and to take the 'Usage per day' from the stock on shelf each day? I have only made very basic macros

Comment: I think the easiest way to accomplish this is having a column 'Stock at starting date' and a starting date. Then, 'Amount in stock'='Stock at starting date'-'Usage per day'*(today()-'Starting date'). Edit: _Gary's Student_ thinks the same.

Answer (score 0):

Place the total amount in stock on 12 July 2016 in column **C** and place the usage per day in column **B**.

Then in **A2** enter:

```
=C2+B2*(DATEVALUE("7/12/2016")-TODAY())
```

and copy down:

[image]

Every day the current amount in column **A** will be reduced by the usage in column **B**.

So on 13-July **A2** will display *598* and on 14-July **A2** will display *527*, etc.

**EDIT#1:**

This is a very simple inventory model.  It is easy to "correct" the model as time passes.

Say on 30-Aug we find that due to weather conditions, usage dropped on the row #13 item and we have a better estimate of the usage as well.  We would:

- set **C13** to the actual on-hand on 30-August
- change the **A13** formula to: `=C13+B13*(DATEVALUE("8/30/2016")-TODAY())`
- place the new usage estimate in **B13**

Comment: Brilliant. I will test this out and get back to you as soon as possible. What would happen if I was to change the vale within current amount in stock?

Comment: @OdhranO'Callaghan  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: Very nice. Easily adjustable then so do I need to change the date ONLY when I am changing either the current stock or usage per day? Apologies for the basic questions excel really isn't my area

Comment: @OdhranO'Callaghan  **Yes** - changing the date in the **A13** formula basically "resets" that row to start over from 30-Aug

Comment: Great! And if I was to try to get the cell to appear red if there was say for example less than 10% of initial stock left could I do this?

Comment: @OdhranO'Callaghan  I would use Conditional Formatting

Comment: Found that. It looks pretty ok to figure out. Thanks. Quick question if you don't mind: Where did you learn excel?

Comment: I learn at work.  Some one named *Gary* taught me.